# Правописание «исчезать» (вид орфограммы)

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правописание согласной в слове "и**с**чезать".
Это какая орфограмма? Или слово словарное?

Comment: Почему нельзя написать "Это какая орфограмма" после тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *исчезать* возникло в древнерусском. Образовано от *чезать* = пропадать, приставка *из-* в значении устранения, удаления.

В современном языке приставка в этом слове не выделяется, сочетание *сч* находится внутри корня, написание его никаким правилам не подчиняется. Тот же звук [ш'ш'], что имеет место в слове *исчезать*, написанном с *сч*, мог бы произноситься и  на месте сочетаний *зч, шч, жч.*

Словарное слово.